# No resource found that matches the given name: attr ‘android:keyboardNavigationCluster’

Tags: android, node.js, angular, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm currently experiencing this weird error in my Ionic project when trying to use `ionic cordova run android --prod`. I've tried removing and readding the platform, removing and readding node modules, and switching npm and node versions to no avail.

**Question: Does anyone have any idea on how to resolve this cryptic issue?**

```
C:\...\platforms\android\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\values-v26\values-v26.xml:15:
```

`error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:keyboardNavigationCluster'.`

```
FAILED

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 26.595 secs

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
C:\...\platforms\android\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\values-v26\values-v26.xml:15:21-54: AAPT: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:keyboardNavigationCluster'.

C:\...\platforms\android\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\values-v26\values-v26.xml:15: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:keyboardNavigationCluster'.



FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

[ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova run android (exit code 1).
Ionic info: (run ionic info from a terminal/cmd prompt and paste output below):

cli packages: (C:…\node_modules)

@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.12.0
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.12.0
global packages:

cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.0.0
local packages:

@ionic/app-scripts : 3.0.0
Cordova Platforms  : android 6.2.3
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.7.1
System:

Android SDK Tools : 25.2.5
Node              : v6.11.4
npm               : 3.10.10
OS                : Windows 10
Misc:

backend : legacy
```

**EDIT: Per request here is my list of cordova plugins**

```
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-app-version" spec="^0.1.9" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" spec="^2.4.1">
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-compat" spec="^1.2.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="^1.1.6" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-file" spec="^4.3.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-file-transfer" spec="^1.6.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-filepath" spec="^1.1.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" spec="^2.4.3">
        <variable name="GEOLOCATION_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value="To determine geolocation for clock in/out purposes." />
    </plugin>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" spec="^1.7.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="^4.0.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="^2.2.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="^1.3.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova.plugins.diagnostic" spec="^3.6.8" />
    <engine name="android" spec="~6.2.3" />
```

Comment: Could you please add the list of cordova plugins you are using?

Comment: Done @David, let me know if you need any other information to diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is most probably related to the cordova diagnostic plugin. Try installing version `3.7.1` which should fix the issue:

```
cordova plugin add cordova.plugins.diagnostic@3.7.1
```

The root cause is that gradle is looking for v26 resource which it does not find. It is explained in more detail [here](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin/issues/240#issuecomment-334078396).

You may also have to update cordova-android to version `6.3.0` (`cordova platform add android@6.3.0`) and upgrade to the most recent Android SDK Tools (via Android Studio). Don't forget to remove `cordova-plugin-compat` when you do so.

Comment: I get this error now Failed for task ':transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lorg/apache/cordova/BuildHelper;

Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

Comment: You have to remove cordova-plugin-compat when using version 6.3.0 because its code is now included in cordova-android. `cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-compat --force`

Comment: Now I just run into this issue > ionic cordova prepare android
> cordova prepare android
Error: Cannot find plugin.xml for plugin "cordova-plugin-compat". Please try adding it again.

[ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova prepare android (exit code 1).

Comment: I could post my config.xml and package.json if that would help

Comment: You have to remove _all_ references of the compat plugin. Just delete the entries in config.xml and package.json. You can also try to install version 1.2.0 of cordova-plugin-compat (read the note on the github page of the plugin). Maybe one of your plugins has a dependency on this plugin.

Comment: Yeah I had it still sitting around in android.json in the \plugins directory. Thank you so so so much. Very appreciated.